# What is the shortest reserved (example) domain

Tags: dns, iana

[IANA has a list of reserved domains](https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved), in tests and documenation. Most famous are probably example.com and example.org.

For documentation and designs of a system that uses very short URLS, I'm looking for a `t.co` or `bit.ly` equivalent. I could not find any short ones on that IANA resource.

What is the shortest possible, offical "example" or "reserved" domain and therefore URL?

Answer (score 2):

The document you refer to refers to [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) that lists *all* reserved domains that are four TLDs:

```
     .test
     .example
     .invalid
     .localhost
```

and three second level domains:

```
    example.com
    example.net
    example.org
```

The shortest of them is `.test` TLD.

Domains like `t.co` and `bit.ly` are *real* domains with single letter second level domain and regular to letters TLD.

Comment: From that, I understand that e.test would be a valid test domain, comparable to example.com or example.org?